# phalcon router is not working

Tags: php, phalcon

here is my router config for my phalcon multi-module project.

```
$router->add('/'.$key.'/:params', [
    'namespace' => $namespace,
    'module' => $key,
    'controller' => 'index',
    'action' => 'index',
    'params' => 1
])->setName($key);
$router->add('/'.$key.'/:controller/:params', [
    'namespace' => $namespace,
    'module' => $key,
    'controller' => 1,
    'action' => 'index',
    'params' => 2
]);
$router->add('/'.$key.'/:controller/:action/:params', [
    'namespace' => $namespace,
    'module' => $key,
    'controller' => 1,
    'action' => 2,
    'params' => 3
]);
```

With just first route, I can get params from url 'backend/1/2' inside /backend/IndexController/indexAction as below.

```
public function indexAction($param1 = "", $param2 = "")
{ 
  //here $param1 = 1, $param2 = 2
}
```

But with all route added, the params can only be get from `backend/index/index/1/2`(with two extra `index`). How to fix it?

Comment: Are you using `$router = new \Phalcon\Mvc\Router(false);`?

Comment: yes. I'm using it.